# Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM without double encoding

Tags: powershell, encoding, recursion, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have seen several great solutions on this forum to convert to UTF-8 without BOM. I need to be able to convert a series of files as such using powershell or something similar recursively.

If I take a UTF-8 document and convert it to UTF-8 the characters are being double encoded. Is there a way to prevent this behavior or detect if the file is already UTF-8 without BOM?

```
foreach($i in ls -recurse -filter "*.*") {
    if (
        $i.Extension.ToLower() -eq ".html" -or 
        $i.Extension.ToLower() -eq ".htm" -or 
        $i.Extension.ToLower() -eq ".php" -or 
        $i.Extension.ToLower() -eq ".txt"
    ) {
        $MyFile = Get-Content $i.fullname 
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($i.fullname, $MyFile)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply an encoding to `Get-Content`:

```
Get-Content $i.FullName -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: What if I do not know the encoding. We may have a handful of files already encoded as UTF-8. The majority for the first pass will be ANSI (Windows).